# Defining field UserSelectionScope dynamically

Tags: 2013, people-picker, custom-schema

I'm using a Visual Studio SharePoint Solution to create my list instances manually and want to define the *UserSelectionScope* for a field in a list like this (in the *Schema.xml* file):

```
<Field DisplayName="Manager" UserSelectionScope="<MyGroupId>" Type="User" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" Name="Manager" .../>
```

The *Managers* group is created using PowerShell and this is of course done after the *Site* has been created.

**Problem**: The value for the *UserSelectionScope* cannot be changed after the Site is created. And before creating site and the group, I don't know what group ID to specify. The *New-SPGroup* command also does not allow giving a custom group ID as a parameter. How do I get around this?

Comment: I suppose the only possibility is to create a suggestion for MS to change this from ID to name or something like this. In the meantime, you can write some feature event receiver and after activation - set up your column. Orrrr if you do not have possibility to use server side code then I think only PowerShell script incorporated in installation process is possible...